# Find all entire functions with $\int_{\Bbb C} |f(z)|\, dz= 1$

Tags: complex-analysis

I know that an entire function with bounded $L^1$ norm is identically $0$, but I do not know how to attack this problem. Does this contradict the fact I stated about entire functions with bounded $L^1$ norm?

Comment: $dz$ should probably be $dA(z),$ where $A$ is area measure. What do you mean by $L^1$-norm?

Comment: $\int \int_{\Bbb C} |f(x+iy)| dxdy$ is the $L^1$ norm

Answer (score 2):

There are no such functions.

For each $w \in \mathbb C$, we have
$$
|f(w)| \le \int_{\Bbb C} |f(z)|\, dz= 1
$$

Therefore, $f$ is bounded. Since $f$ is entire, $f$ is constant, by Liouville's theorem.

But then we cannot have $\int_{\Bbb C} |f(z)|\, dz= 1$.

Comment: Why is $|f(w)| \le \int_{\Bbb C} |f(z)|\, dz$ valid?

Comment: @md2perpe, because $\displaystyle |f(w)| = \lim_{r\to 0} \int_{D(w,r)} |f(z)|\, dz$.

Comment: there is hint for the problem: to estimate the Taylor coefficients, but i still have no clear idea